# Input data from time series, keeping part of the steps to predict

Tags: keras, lstm

I am using Keras LSTM for time series forecasting.

I am facing an issue, with transforming my data correctly.

I have a big dataset with values as follows
[[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8],
[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8],
[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]....]

I want to predict x8.
x1-x7 are values that are available before x8 is found, and x8 is dependant upon them.

Ideally, as the input into the LSTM, I'd have say 10 rows of all variables and then 5 rows of x1-x7, with the 5 rows of x8 as output, but I am having troubles getting such a vector into it. How should I proceed?